# I want to return from List and foreach of CreateCriteria in c# .net5

Tags: c#, createcriteria

I want to exit when the result is true using ipnetwork.
It exits from foreach, but it doesn't get out of the List and runs again.
please tell me how to solve.

Is there a way to do this without using ActionableList?
Or is there a better way to code?
This is the .net 5 version.

What I am trying to do is to set true if the IP address is included in the allowable range among the registered IP addresses.

```
          bool result = false;

          await Task.Run(() => {
            var q = ss.CreateCriteria<Ip>();

            q.List(new ActionableList<Ip>(r => {
              var ipArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(r.ip_address);

              foreach(var ip in ipArray){
                IPNetwork ipnetwork = IPNetwork.Parse(ip);
                result = ipnetwork.Contains(ipaddress);

                if(result){
                  return;
                }
              }

              if(result){
                return;
              }
            }));
          });
```

Comment: I have never heard of an `ActionableList`. Is this something you created yourself? If so, it's very likely to be relevant to the question. Either way, to me it seems like your code can easily be refactored to use `LINQ` instead: `var hasResult = ipArray.Select(ip => IPNetwork.Parse(ip)).Any(ip => ipnetwork.Contains(ip));`

Comment: Thanks, so is there any way to get out of q.List? When it is true, I need to exit, but I can't.

Comment: You are asking for answers based on API's and implementations which are not in the standard .NET library. It is impossible for me to answer.